# Как задать функцию которая создаст единичную матрицу указанного размера без итераций?

Tags: javascript

```
function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
    let arr = [];

    if (n === 1){
        return [[1]];
    }
    if (n === 0){
        return [];
    }
    return (new Array(n).fill(0)).map(function(item,i,arr) {
        item = (new Array(n).fill(0)).fill(1);

        return arr;
    });
}
```

Моя функция создает матрицу, заполненную нулями. Не получается добавить единицы.

Comment: почему ты не хочешь простой цикл использовать?

Comment: кроме этого, присваивать значение параметру `item` внутри `map` - бессмысленно

Comment: Смысл задачи, сделать ее без loops.

Comment: А это не Вы статьи на хабре пишите? После Вашего прошлого вопроса появилась статья с очень похожими примерами.

Comment: Нет, я на хабре никогда статей не писал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getIdentityMatrix(n) {
    return (new Array(n).fill(0)).map(
        function (a, i){
            return (new Array(n)).fill(0).map(function (b,j){return (i==j)?1:0;});
        }
    )
}

var t=getIdentityMatrix(5);
for(i=0; i<5; i++){console.log(t[i].join(" "))}
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение